# A RenderFlex overflowed by 299423 pixels on the bottom. problem seems to be made by the Column

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, dart

[image]

I'm new to flutter , or programming to be clear .
I was following a course , doing the same as the Instructor , the app worked for him , but when i try to run it ,this error shows up .

**Edit**: tried to change **Column** to **ListView** but an error showed up .

```
 [![// @dart=2.9

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';



class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestion;

  Quiz(
      {@required this.questions,
      @required this.answerQuestion,
      @required this.questionIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: \[
        Question(
          questions\[questionIndex\]\['questionText'\],
        ),
        ...(questions\[questionIndex\]\['answers'\] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer\['score'\]), answer\['text'\]);
        }).toList()
      \],
    );
  }
}][2]][2]
```

Comment: Add Column widget inside SingleChildScrollView() widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SingleChildScrollView( )` is for is for single child (and you have multiple)

Consider replacing your `Column (children : [...])` with

```
ListView(

   children: [...]

);
```

rather than wrapping Column in `SingleChildScrollView()` this way you won't run into issues down the road

Comment: replacing **Column** with **ListView** created another problem which is as following : 
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Answer(dirty):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'

Comment: Could you edit your question with the full code leading to this error i’ll try to help you out - list view is really best to use here

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the list view... you'll see it still happens with Column & SingleChildScrollView - accept this answer & open an other one for this second issue - i'll see you there

Comment: also clean up your code what are all the \\\\\\\\ about ?